# Multiple Programs in WebGL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm trying to use multiple shader programs in webgl but continue to get issues.

It seems that if i have a different number of vertex shader attributes in programs then i get nothing rendered with no errors. Is there some constraint that means that programs have to have the same number of attributes? Do i need to disable/enable attribute locations when changing programs?

It seems that just creating multiple programs causes the issue ( i dont even have to use the second shader, just the fact that it is created causes the issue).

To create the attributes i'm using the following snippet (works fine when number of attributes in all programs is the same):

```
for ( var i=0 ; i<vertexAttributes.length ; i++ )
{
   shaderProgram[vertexAttributes[i].name] = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,vertexAttributes[i].name);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram[vertexAttributes[i].name]);
}
```

---

Sorry for posting such a large chunk of code, but this best illustrates the issue. this is code from one of the learningwebgl.com tutorials, all that i have done is add a second pair of shaders ("shader2-fs" and "shader2-vs") and a new function called initShaders2. if initShaders2 is called in webGLStart() (as it is in the code) then nothing is drawn??? i'm baffled!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="two_files/glMatrix-0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="two_files/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vColor = aVertexColor;
    }
</script>

<script id="shader2-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader2-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

    uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
    uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;

    uniform bool uUseLighting;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

        if (!uUseLighting) {
            vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        } else {
            vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
            float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
            vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
        }
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var gl;

    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }


    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }

        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }

        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }


    var shaderProgram;

    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    }


    var shaderProgram2;

    function initShaders2() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader2-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader2-vs");

        shaderProgram2 = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram2, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram2, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram2);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram2, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram2);

        shaderProgram2.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram2, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram2.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram2.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram2, "aVertexNormal");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram2.vertexNormalAttribute);

        shaderProgram2.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram2, "aTextureCoord");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram2.textureCoordAttribute);

        shaderProgram2.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram2.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uMVMatrix");
        shaderProgram2.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uNMatrix");
        shaderProgram2.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uSampler");
        shaderProgram2.useLightingUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uUseLighting");
        shaderProgram2.ambientColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uAmbientColor");
        shaderProgram2.lightingDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uLightingDirection");
        shaderProgram2.directionalColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uDirectionalColor");
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var mvMatrixStack = [];
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function mvPushMatrix() {
        var copy = mat4.create();
        mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
        mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
    }

    function mvPopMatrix() {
        if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
            throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
        }
        mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    }


    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }


    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }


    var pyramidVertexPositionBuffer;
    var pyramidVertexColorBuffer;
    var cubeVertexPositionBuffer;
    var cubeVertexColorBuffer;
    var cubeVertexIndexBuffer;

    function initBuffers() {
        pyramidVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
        var vertices = [
            // Front face
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Back face
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Left face
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 12;

        pyramidVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
        var colors = [
            // Front face
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

            // Right face
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

            // Back face
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

            // Left face
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
        pyramidVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 12;


        cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
        vertices = [
            // Front face
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

            // Back face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Top face
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

            // Bottom face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Left face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

        cubeVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexColorBuffer);
        colors = [
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Front face
            [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Back face
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Top face
            [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0], // Bottom face
            [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], // Right face
            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]  // Left face
        ];
        var unpackedColors = [];
        for (var i in colors) {
            var color = colors[i];
            for (var j=0; j < 4; j++) {
                unpackedColors = unpackedColors.concat(color);
            }
        }
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(unpackedColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        cubeVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
        cubeVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 24;

        cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
        var cubeVertexIndices = [
            0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
            4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
            8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
            12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
            16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
            20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
        cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;
    }


    var rPyramid = 0;
    var rCube = 0;

    function drawScene() {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -8.0]);

        mvPushMatrix();
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rPyramid), [0, 1, 0]);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

        mvPopMatrix();


        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [3.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

        mvPushMatrix();
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rCube), [1, 1, 1]);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexColorBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, cubeVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        mvPopMatrix();

    }


    var lastTime = 0;

    function animate() {
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastTime != 0) {
            var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

            rPyramid += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
            rCube -= (75 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        }
        lastTime = timeNow;
    }


    function tick() {
        requestAnimFrame(tick);
        drawScene();
        animate();
    }


    function webGLStart() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson04-canvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders2();  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        tick();
    }

</script>


</head>


<body onload="webGLStart();">
    <a href="http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370">&lt;&lt; Back to Lesson 4</a><br>

    <canvas id="lesson04-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    <br>
    <a href="http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370">&lt;&lt; Back to Lesson 4</a><br>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll probably need to give us a little bit more information, but to get you started here's a quick checklist. Any time you change programs, you'll want to:

- Enable the appropriate vertex attribute arrays
- Bind the vertex attribute pointers, even if they were already bound to the right buffers
- Bind any uniforms needed, like texture samplers.

Basically, you want to treat every time you change programs as if it's the first time you're setting up a draw call.

Comment: thanks for the insight! i didn't give enough info for you to solve it, but the info you gave set my mind thinking the right way. cheers!